# Java hangman end loop

Tags: java

Please help me, I need to know how to end this loop three times. But how, if you know please tell me I've been working day and night. And may the Code be with you all!(Star Wars)

```
System.out.println("If you want to leave, type \"quit\"");
System.out.println("If you want to play again,type\"yes\" ");

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String s=input.next();
if(s.equals("quit")) {
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing the game!");
    System.exit(0);
}
if (s.equals("yes")) {     
    String userInput = input.nextLine();
    userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
    startGame();
```

Here is the full code:

```
import static Hello.Hangman.startGame;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Hangman {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hangman game = new Hangman();
        Hangman.startGame();
    }


    public static void startGame() {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String first, reverse = "";
        String second, reverse2 = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!");
        System.out.println("Enter your first name.");
        first = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your last name to play.");
        second = in.nextLine();

        int length = first.length();
        int length2 = second.length();
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse = reverse + first.charAt(i);
        reverse = reverse.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()++ reverse.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        for (int i = length2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse2 = reverse2 + second.charAt(i);
        reverse2 = reverse2.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + reverse2.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        System.out.println("Your name entered in reverse    is: " + reverse + " " + reverse2);
        System.out.println("Press enter to continue:");
        in.nextLine();

        String[] CollectionOfWords =
                {"", "world", "about", "again", "heart", "pizza",
                        "earth", "stars", "light", "music", "party",
                        "seven", "three", "happy", "water", "amber",
                        "apple", "piano", "green", "mouth", "suger",
                        "stone", "japan", "china", "after", "smile",
                        "south", "house", "stake", "guess", "wrong",
                        "thing", "write", "white", "black", "lemon",
                        "anime", "stick", "outer", "input", "grand",
                        "lives", "twice", "print", "hangs", "woman",
                        "power", "today", "india", "night", "candy",
                        "puppy", "latin", "vegan", "phone", "april",
                        "forum", "birth", "other", "chris", "irish",
                        "paste", "queen", "grace", "crazy", "plant",
                        "knife", "spike", "darth", "vader", "eagle",
                        "egypt", "range", "fists", "fight", "glory",
                        "March", "smart", "magic", "codes", "rolls",
                        "match", "honor", "glass", "board", "teams",
                        "bully", "zebra", "under", "mango", "brain",
                        "dirty", "eight", "zeros", "train", "cycle",
                        "break", "necks", "terms", "slide", "large"};


        int randNumber = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * CollectionOfWords.length);
        int counter = 5;
        String radmWord = CollectionOfWords[randNumber];

        char[] genRadmLetter = radmWord.toCharArray();
        char[] genRadmLetter2 = radmWord.toCharArray();
        for (int x = 0; x < genRadmLetter.length; x++) {
            genRadmLetter[x] = '-';
        }

        System.out.println(String.valueOf(genRadmLetter));
        System.out.println("Hello" + " " + reverse + " " + reverse2 + " " + "guess a letter");
        char guessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);
        int RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter);

        if (RW >= 0) {

            genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
            System.out.println(genRadmLetter);

        }

        if (RW == -1) {
            System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
            counter = counter - 1;
            System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
        }

        while (counter != 0) {

            System.out.println("Guess a letter.");
            guessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);
            RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter);

            if (RW >= 0) {

                genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
                System.out.println(genRadmLetter);


            }

            if (RW == -1) {
                System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
                counter = counter - 1;
                System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
            }

            boolean result = Arrays.equals(genRadmLetter, genRadmLetter2);
            if (result == true) {

                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < genRadmLetter.length; i++) {
                if (radmWord.charAt(i) == guessedLetter) {
                    genRadmLetter[i] = guessedLetter;
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            if (counter == 0) {
                break;
            }

        }

        if (counter == 0) {
            System.out.println("You lost. The word was: " + radmWord);
            playAgain();

            if (RW == 0)
                System.out.println("Well done, you have guessed the word.");
            System.out.println("Your final score is: " + counter);


        }
    }

    public static boolean playAgain() {

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("If you want to leave, type \"quit\"");
            System.out.println("If you want to play again,type\"yes\" ");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s = input.next();
            if (s.equals("quit")) {
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing the game!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (s.equals("yes")) {

                String userInput = input.nextLine();
                userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
                startGame();


            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I need to know how to end this loop three times* means ?? you wanted to execute it 3 times ??

Comment: Yes, please help

Comment: Indentation is very important It allows us to see actual scope of code sections which prevents many mistakes. Use tools your editor provide and indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

instead

```
while (true) {
```

you can have counter

```
int count=0;
while (count<3) {
count++;
```

Comment: try this code, if it works then don't forget to accept

Comment: what doesn't work ?? you need to clarify. Technically, it should iterate 3 times.

Comment: I wanted "StartGame" to only work three times then it would say my total score from each round. but it doesn't work? Please help me.

Comment: Can you be more clear? the code is not working at all.

Comment: I should ask this question to you. If code is not at all working, then make it work. We can correct logical error, we can't write complete code for you

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to impress a very important person in my life and I need help.

Comment: Dude, then you need to work hard. And, make this code work by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use do while loop

```
      `int ch=0;
      do{if (s.equals("yes")) {
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
       userInput = userInput.toUpperCase();
        startGame();ch++; 
        }     while(ch<3);`
```